# Editing TextView text inside of listView via a button

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I have the ListView.I have also the button. They are inside of RelativeLayout. I want to be able to change TexView text of selected ListView item via the button onClick(View v).
ListView layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="22px"
        android:layout_height="22px"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4px"
        android:layout_marginRight="10px"
        android:layout_marginTop="4px"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@+id/label"
        android:textSize="20px" >
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private TextView mTextView;
    private ListView my_list;
    private MyArrayAdapter adapt;
    Button mybutton;

    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle); 

        String[] mContacts = {
                "Jacob Anderson dsfd sdfdf sdfsd sdfds", "Emily Duncan", "Michael Fuller", 
                "Emma Greenman", "Joshua Harrison", "Madison Johnson",
                "Matthew Cotman", "Olivia Lawson", "Andrew Chapman", 
                "Daniel Honeyman", "Isabella Jackson", "William Patterson", 
                "Joseph Godwin", "Samantha Bush", "Christopher Gatema55"};

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        my_list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        adapt=new MyArrayAdapter(this, mContacts, 0);
        my_list.setAdapter(adapt);

        mybutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        mybutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {     
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

What should I do if I want to edit TextView like this:

```
        SpannableString text = new SpannableString("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet");
    text.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, 5, 0);
    TextViewOfSelectedItem.setText(text, BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

How can I get the TextViewOfSelectedItem or TextView of ListView item via item position?

Comment: You can change the string in your String array (after you click the button) and reload the adapter.

Comment: I have updated the question. I want to access a TextView for editing

Comment: Use the `getChildAt(int index)` method of your listview item(which is view). Usually you see those items in the debugger.

Comment: "Use the getChildAt(int index) method of your listview item(which is view)." - Yes, it gives me the way to do thing I want to do. It seems that problem is resolved. Thanks.

Comment: BTW getChildAt(int index) accesses items that is shown on screen while  getItemAtPosition(int index) access items among all ListView items.

Answer (score 0):

You can get text of selected item by using `setOnItemClickListener()`. You can use this way.

```
    my_list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
 long arg3) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String  getSelectedTextOfList = yourList.get(pos); // here you can get selected item.
 }
});
```